# XPath Data Scraping From Online Community

Tags: excel, xpath, web-scraping

I recently read this [article](http://www.matthewbarby.com/scraping-communities-with-xpath/) on how to scrape the Inbound.org community members profile using Excel. And you can watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaN2J6JGv6U) here if you prefer it that way.

Since the release of this tutorial, the Inbound website structure has changed a bit, as you can see at minute 11:00 in the video, if you attempt to copy the XPath of the social media icons it appears slightly different and because of this I haven't been able to extract that information.

Here's what I get now:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[1]/i
```

This is how I wrote the syntax in Excel:

```
=XPathOnUrl(A2,"//a[@class='twitter']","href")
```

And then like this:

```
=XPathOnUrl(A2,"//a[contains(@class,twitter)]/@href")
```

Although I tried in many different ways, none of them showed me the link to the member's social media profile.

I even tried changing the xpath in multiple ways to get different data from the page, but none of it was the social media information:

```
=XPathOnUrl(A2,"//*[contains(@class,member-banner-tagline)]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]")

=XPathOnUrl(A2,"//*[contains(@class,member-banner-tagline)]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/h1")
```

I honestly don't know what to try anymore, something's wrong and I can't figure it out. Anybody have enough experience with this or can pinpoint the problem here with my syntax?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The first formula you tried looks fine, but this is the one that works for me (SEO Tools version 4.3.4) :

```
=Dump(XPathOnUrl(A2;"//a[@class='twitter']";"href";HttpSettings(TRUE)))
```

Comment: I tried your formula and I get an error from Excel saying it found a problem with the formula and I have to change it. I also use SEO Tools version 4.3.4

Comment: Ok, I got the right one. Here's how: =Dump(XPathOnUrl(A2,"//*/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a[1]","href"))